# Javascript search value

Tags: javascript, json, api

my search query is not working and I don't know why!

I have inserted a button to run the function and a function to accept the variable from search, yet tho, the code gets stuck with a default that I don't even know where it's getting from...

```html
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Timezone API</h1>
</div>
<div class="error-message"></div>
<input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Insert location"></input>
<button type="button" onClick="getTimezone()">Search</button>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  getTimezone();
})

function searchlocation() {
  var searchQuery = $(".search").val();
  getTimezone(searchQuery);
}

async function getTimezone(searchQuery) {
  var url = "https://timezone.abstractapi.com/v1/current_time/?api_key=[REDACTED]&location=" + searchQuery;

  $.ajax(url, {
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
    }
  })
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You might not want to post your API key publicly. I recommend you revoke it now

Comment: You have a typo in your code, there's an extra `}` after the `success` handler in your AJAX call. Remove that and your code works.

Comment: Also note that I edited your question so that the code is formatted correctly, which makes it much easier to spot this kind of mistake. I'd suggest you download an IDE which does this for you - and includes a linter to immediately show you code errors. Also, learn to use browser devtools to debug JS as this syntax issue will be shown there.

Comment: Just a quick second on @evolutionxbox comment. That key is in the edit history for this question and needs to be revoked asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it's because you're using the wrong function here:

```
<button type="button" onClick="getTimezone()">Search</button>
```

I think you want to use `searchlocation()` there, not `getTimezone()`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getTimezone()` without any parameter however your function implementation expects one.

My guess is that you want to return the promise from getTimezone func and call it on button click while the value for the query is taken from the text field

```html
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Timezone API</h1>
</div>
<div class="error-message"></div>
<input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Insert location"></input>
<button type="button">Search</button>
```

```js
async function getTimezone(searchQuery) {
  var url = "https://timezone.abstractapi.com/v1/current_time/?api_key=[REDACTED]&location=" + searchQuery;

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    $.ajax(url, {
      success: function(data) {
        resolve(data);
      }
    })
  })
}


$("button")
  .on("click", async function(){
    const val = $(".search").val();
    const result = await getTimezone(val);
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Comment: Your code throws an error, two actually.. 

"Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules (at VM433 main.js:27:20)
main.js:27 Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules (at main.js:27:20)
(index):45 Uncaught ReferenceError: getTimezone is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):45:51)"

Comment: How do I make it so the function waits for location without prompting error straight away?

Comment: Updated, async flag was missing